# I asked a question about what was wrong with my code and it was put on hold with no given specific reason

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, moderation

Now this was my question:
[NullPointerException on going to another activity, android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19064834/nullpointerexception-on-going-to-another-activity-android-studio)

I searched a lot of other questions and answers on Stack Overflow and none of them were similar to my case, so I asked a new question. 5 or 6 people tried to help me so gratefully and I tried all their solutions and answered immediately with the results and logcat reports.

None of them solved my problem and I still have no answer to what is causing the problem.
Someone with 6kish reputation comes and comments that he "thinks" I don't have enough understanding about my problem and I have to first study OOP and Java and then start writing programs. I tried to be polite and answered him that I appreciated his opinion but I'm practicing to learn, which he then answers me because of an answer I gave to a comment who someone posted with really bad and unclear English he thinks that "any answer he would give me, I would not understand."

Now I was being polite, I'm a software engineering third year university student and I'm quite sure I will understand any answer to my question really good.

Today I come and see my question is put on hold with no specific reason at all, and there is no mechanic for someone like me to ask a moderator for an un-hold.

It would be really nice if Stack Overflow had a feature for us to apply a request in order to put our question out of on hold state.

Just wanted to know what is really going on.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Thanks a lot. I think I'm getting the hang of it. Really tnx for the feedback.

Comment: Simply edit your question once and it will go for review to be reopened. Make sure to include specifics about your issue, such as any suspicions as to what is going wrong (don't need to be exact, but at least showing that you've tried to solve the issue).

Comment: Trust me, that's not _near_ the worst I've seen around here.  Also, try and word your question to give what you can tell from the logcat.

Comment: A few things here: Leave all the chat from the question. Being new and stuck and so on. This is all just noise. Reduce the code to the minimum (What's with all the empty code lines?). And you don't even say what your code should do.

Comment: Yeah after I posted this, a kind person named NoIdeaForName told me that I had to reduce my code to areas I though were causing the problem. I thanked him and I'm editing my post right now.

Comment: And point to the line the exception occours. It is mentioned in the error (Activity.java:1647)

Comment: What I'm trying to say, is that a simple edit suggestion or a comment could do the work and I would make my question better. Putting it on hold, is another thing though.

Comment: There are a lot things to change here and you could have done it. And putting it on hold is a remainder to do so. Do it and it gets opened. That is the whole point of putting on hold

Comment: @juergend really thanks for your help and guidance. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: The On Hold text below your question would have included a reason. A question is **never** put on hold without one. It looks as if your question has been improved enough and reopened in the meantime.

Comment: This happened indeed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When a question is put on hold, you can edit the question to get it in the re-open queue or flag your own question for moderation attention. I agree that this is not a question 'asking for code' as the close reason suggests, but a 'question about problems with existing code'. The offtopic reasons say:

> Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and 
>   include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

While you paste your code there, the idea behind this is that you debug your own code, remove all unnecessary balast until you have the bare minimum amount of code to reproduce the problem. That should make it a lot easier for yourself too to figure out what the exact problem is.

That said I think that 6k rep user makes a fair point though. Debugging involves more than staring at error logs. Do some trial and error, figure out what is in variables and what should be in them. Comment out part of the code until it works again and look at what might be wrong in the part of the code you commented out. One of the answers actually solved your error, but gave you an other error instead. That should give you a better clue of what might be wrong with your code, and you should have at least tried to get that solution working. Instead you wait until that person will magically fix all your problems. The question itself is currently not much more than "this is my code, debug it for me" and that is not what SO is for.